# AWS and Railo setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, railo, cfml

I wondered if anyone can point me in the right direction in regards to installing [Railo](http://getrailo.org) on AWS.

In my spare time I've put together a website to sell illustrations, but due to cost I'm unable to keep on spending money hosting it on a dedicate CF server with almost zero budget for marketing. I've been toying with the idea of setting up an account with Amazon and installing Railo.

Over the past few months I've had different advice, such as get a S3 account to host the images and an EC2 account for Railo for the website and DB with SSL, or just have S3 account where I will be able to host Railo and have my images on the same server. I'm not sure what is best and I was wondering if you can advise what you think a good solution would be.

I've read a few blogs some with good details on setups but they seem to be over a year+ old, so I'm not sure if they are valid solution any more. It's very much over my head, as I'm a developer, but I'm very eager to learn new things especially about the cloud service as it's not a common area to get involved in when working for companies. In the past I used to tag a long to server rooms and understand the infrastructure but now everything is done remotely and it's not so easy to get involved.

Any basic advice/advanced advice from your experiences of what I should follow and if you know of any good resources would be very much appreciated.

Should I get an S3 and EC2 AWS setup or will one of them do (will need DB connectivity)?

Load balancing two EC2 instances will that be hard to configure, I will need to web servers.

Answer (score 2):

I just posted this very topic a few weeks ago.  Should still be more than up to date:
http://blog.nictunney.com/2012/03/railo-tomcat-and-apache-on-amazon-ec2.html

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the link, its actually one of the first blogs i came across also found http://www.designfrontier.net/articles/?id=12 which is a good article but its a few years old. Unfortunately neither answer my questions.